# Laravel routes overwriting phpmyadmin path with nginx

Tags: ubuntu, laravel, nginx

I have the following nginx config on my LEMP droplet:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/html/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name server_domain_or_IP;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I would like to run PHPMyAdmin together with Laravel on/phpmyadmin but only the Laravel routes get served to the browser. So any /phpmyadmin would be parsed as a route where it isn't one.

I have tried multiple things

- Adding my own location `/phpmyadmin` above the `location ~ \.php` even trying `^~ /phpmyadmin` to force precedence.
- I've set my root to /usr/share/phpmyadmin, without any results.
- I have tried copying the fastcgi options and basically copying the complete logic but using /phpmyadmin without any result either

I am pretty sure it's probably a small thing that I am missing.

Comment: Any solution? I tried everything

Comment: I still haven't found a perfect solution, I am currently using a subdomain... and set the hosts file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following code worked for me (added before the "`location ~ \.php$ {`"-part:

```
location /phpmyadmin {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
                    try_files $uri =404;
                    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            }
            location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
                    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            }
    }
```

Just make sure to adjust the three "root" locations to the folder where your "phpmyadmin" folder is in (the location of my phpmyadmin folder is here: "**/usr/share/nginx/html/phpmyadmin**"

Comment: Your solution is perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your phpmyadmin configuration file is /etc/phpmyadmin/nginx-php5-fpm.conf

Try adding this to your nginx config before location{}:

```
include /etc/phpmyadmin/nginx-php5-fpm.conf;
```

add this into your phpmyadmin.conf

```
location /pma {
    alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin/;
}

location ~ ^/pma/(.*\.(js|css|gif|jpg|png))$ {
    alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin/$1;
}

location ~ ^/pma(.+\.php)$ {
    alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin$1;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;

    charset utf8;

    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
}
```

Your phpmyadmin will be accessible through http://yourdomain/pma

Enjoy !

Answer (score 0):

In our case, we used the following steps:

Created a location config at - `/etc/nginx/conf.d/phpmyadmin.location`

```
location ~* /dbmyadmin {
    root /var/www;
    index index.php;
       location ~ ^/dbmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
           root /var/www;
           fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
           fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
           include fastcgi_params;
           include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
      }

   location ~* ^/dbmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
        root /var/www;
    }
}
```

And Included this config file into the default config file.

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/phpmyadmin.location;
```

**Note:**
You can replace the PHP version and path as per your
requirement.

Make sure you have created a short link of PHPMyAdmin directory to `/var/www` directory with name `dbmyadmin`

```
ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/dbmyadmin
```