# Laravel5 and PhpMyadmin on Digital Ocean LEMP stack

Tags: nginx, digital-ocean

I tried to install phpMyadmin on my LEMP server using following tutorial

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-phpmyadmin-on-a-lemp-server

but when I try to access myip/phpmyadmin I get page cannot be found

before this I installed laravel5 so anything i am typing after ip/anystring its being accessed by my laravel route page ,

So can you tell me how I can access the phpMyadmin

my ip is http://xxxxxxxx//phpmyadmin .

and my default page for nginx looks like this

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

root /var/www/laravel/public;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

# Make site accessible from http://localhost/
server_name xxxxxxx;

location / {
# First attempt to serve request as file, then
# as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
# Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
# include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
}

error_page 404 /404.html;
error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
try_files $uri =404;
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi_params;
}

}
```

Please hlp me out 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am also stuck in the same kind of situation. Paste this code before location ~ .php$ function and it's work perfectly fine.

Source : [Laravel routes overwriting phpmyadmin path with nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28659068/laravel-routes-overwriting-phpmyadmin-path-with-nginx)

```
location /phpmyadmin {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
                    try_files $uri =404;
                    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            }
            location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
                    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            }
    }
```